# If this = first <li> with the class of 'xyz' then run function

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-cycle

I've got a `<ul>` with 6 items. Each item has a class of either planning, landscape or environmental. The items are part of a jQuery Cycle slideshow on the page. What I am intending to do is show something on the page if the list item that is being displayed is the first item with a specific class.

As you can see below, I have two list items with the class of 'planning'. How would I detect if the list item being displayed is the first with the class of 'planning'?.

Cycle gives me a great little function to help me, I'm just not sure how to write the `if()` inside my helper function to trigger the item I want to display on the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

** Edit ** Here's the jsFiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/73y2R/1](http://%20jsfiddle.net/73y2R/1)

Here's the html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="planning">
        <img src="images/pl_slide1.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li class="planning">
        <img src="images/pl_slide1.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li class="landscape">
        <img src="images/la_slide2.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li class="landscape">
        <img src="images/la_slide2.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li class="environmental">
        <img src="images/en_slide1.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li class="environmental">
        <img src="images/en_slide1.jpg">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And the helper function:

```
function onBefore() {
var theid = $(this).attr('class');
$('#services h4').removeClass('recolor');
$('#slideShow ul li').removeClass('showTitle');
if($(this).hasClass('planning')){
    $('#arrow').animate({'paddingLeft':'60px'});
    $('#' + theid).addClass('recolor');
} else if ($(this).hasClass('landscape')){
    $('#arrow').animate({'paddingLeft':'330px'});
    $('#' + theid).addClass('recolor'); 
} else if ($(this).hasClass('environmental')){
    $('#arrow').animate({'paddingLeft':'598px'});
    $('#' + theid).addClass('recolor'); 
}
}
```

Comment: It should be noted, in addition to using `first` you can use the JQ selector `first-child` if you wish this occur on multiple instances. And, assuming you only wanted to apply styles (and not effects/functions), you could use the CSS `first-child` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>if($(this).is("li.planning:first")){
     //This is the first li...
    }</del>

Am not sure why the first version is not working (may be issues with jQuery extension pseudo classes with is method ???).

Use `$(this).is($("li.planning:first"))` instead of  `$(this).is("li.planning:first")` (We are passing a jQuery object to the is method instead of a string selector)

Try this:

```
if($(this).is($("li.planning:first"))){
 //This is the first li...
}
```

Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73y2R/2/

Comment: Dang, I really wanted this one to work... For some reason when I ad the pseudo class it breaks. I modified my function to `if($(this).is('#slideShow ul li.planning')){`... and it continues to work. But if I do `if($(this).is('#slideShow ul li.planning:first')){` the items in the if statement don't execute.

Comment: I tried this last night but kept getting a timeout error over at jsFiddle. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73y2R/1/

Comment: @Cybermate Well done! Thank you, thank you. It never cases to amaze me what simple things will cripple a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just do

```
$('li.xyz:first')
```

As your selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_planning_child = $('li.planning')[0]; // and so on. I think the :first, :first-child, etc. selectors have cross browser issues, but I can't recall if that's correct.
$(first_planning_child).doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/hwzyx/1/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstClass = $("ul li:first-child").attr('class');

    var isPlanning;
    ($.trim(firstClass) == 'planning') ? isPlanning = true : isPlanning = false;

    var isLandscape;
    ($.trim(firstClass) == 'landscape') ? isLandscape = true : isLandscape = false;

    var isEnvironmental;
    ($.trim(firstClass) == 'environmental') ? isEnvironmental = true : isEnvironmental = false;

    if(isPlanning)
        alert('First child class is planning');

    if(isLandscape)
        alert('First child class is landscape');

    if(isEnvironmental)
        alert('First child class is environmental');
});
```

Regards :-)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

Based on issues you are having... use the arguments of `before` option, you want the next slide not the current one as `before` triggers before `this` becomes the next slide

```
 function onBefore(curr, next, opts){
      var $next= $(next);
      var theid = $next.attr('class');

 }
```